# How to statically link Qt image formats plugins for WebKit?

Tags: c++, image, qt, plugins, qwebview

I need a `QWebView` to display images, instead of the question marks it currently displays.

I have found that i need to link some image plugins to my application to do so. I have researched this problem for a while now, and I haven't found a satisfying solution.

**I followed these steps:**

**1)** I have added in my project folder and the folder in which the application is compiled a folder named: `imageformats/` in which i have put these folowing plugins: `libqgif.so` and `libqjpeg.so`

**2)** I have added to my project configuration file (.pro) this:

```
 QTPLUGIN     += qjpeg \
                 qgif
```

**3)** And I have added to the .cpp containg the main function of my project this:

```
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qjpeg)
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qgif)
```

And i get the following errors:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xce): undefined reference to `qt_plugin_instance_qjpeg()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xda): undefined reference to `qt_plugin_instance_qgif()'
```

I also tried changing the directory to `plugins/imageformats/`, but it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: How did you obtain / build Qt? This should "just work," at least in Qt Creator. I have an application displaying JPEG images and didn't need any extra code at all ... no QTPLUGIN, Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN, etc. When I *deploy*, then I include the plugins just like you have.

Comment: I downloaded qt creator from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

For me (on Ubuntu 12.04), I didn't have libjpeg and dev headers installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

(which will also install libjpeg62 if you don't have it).

After this, my QTWebView showed jpeg images without any extra modifications.